# How to design database system of an online toy shop?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, database-design

**Hi i'm designing a database for a toy shop this shop offer many products with different categories. This is the project question. Can you please help me which tables and relationships should I add in my database. i am a beginner and have no idea about it.**

The proposed project aims to develop a comprehensive database system, For an online Toy Shop, Facilitating Efficient Management of Inventory, Sales, Customer Data, And Overall Business Operations. With the growing demand For Online Shopping, Particularly in the toy industry, The Implementation of a Robust Database System is critical to ensure seamless transactions, streamlined inventory management system, and enhanced customer experiences. This Proposal Outlines a Structured approach to Design, Develop, and Implement a user-friendly and scalable database system tailored to the Specific requirements of the Online Toy Shop.

**Project Objectives:**

- Design and develop a centralized database system to manage and
  monitor. The inventory of various toys, including details, such as
  product descriptions, pricing, and availability. Aeroplane toy with
  usability and price and quantity available etc.
- Implement a    User-Friendly interface for managing customer
  information, orders,    and transactions, enabling efficient tracking
  and processing of    online purchases.
- Integrate a secure payment    gateway within the    Database System
  To Facilitate Secure And    Seamless Financial    Transactions For
  Customers.
- Create a    Comprehensive Reporting System    to Generate
  Analytical Insights On    Sales Trends, Popular Products,    and
  customer Preferences to    Facilitate Data-Driven Decision-Making.

**Scope Of Work:**

- Conduct a Detailed Analysis Of The Online Toy Shop's Business
  Requirements And Operational Processes To Identify Specific Data
  Management Needs.
- Design and develop a relational database system architecture with a
  dashboard that encompasses product inventory, customer data,
  transaction Records, And Reporting Functionalities.
- Implement Secure Data Encryption Protocols (DEP) and authentication
  mechanisms to safeguard sensitive customer information and financial
  transactions.
- Create Intuitive User Interfaces For Both Customers And
  Administrative Staff, for seamless navigation and Efficient Data
  Management Capabilities.
- Conduct Rigorous Testing And Debugging to ensure the Reliability,
  Scalability, and Security of the Database System under various
  operational Scenarios.

I have collected some data for the database please guide me which tables, attributes and relations I can add.

**Product Table:**

```
product_id (primary key)
product_name
product_description
product_price
product_quantity
product_image
Product_Catagory
```

**Customer:**

```
customer_id (primary key)
customer_name
customer_email
Customer Shipping Address
Customer Billing Address
customer_phone_number
```

**Order:**

```
order_id (primary key)
customer_id (foreign key)
product_id (foreign key)
order_date
order_quantity
order_status
```

**Transaction**

```
transaction_id (primary key)
order_id (foreign key)
payment_method
payment_amount
payment_date
Transaction Status
```

**Table: Users**

```
user_id (Primary Key)
username
password (encrypted and securely stored)
role (customer, admin)
```

**Table: Reports**

```
report_id (Primary Key)
report_name
generated_by (admin/user)
generation_date
```

Also describe how I can create relation ship between tables.

Comment: Is this homework?  If not, this is not a task for a "beginner with no idea" .....

Comment: There are many Questions on the forum that talk about details of such tables.  Find them and see if you like any of them.

Answer (score -2):

There are essentially 3 types of Relationship:

1-to-1 -- This should usually be avoided.  Simply combine tht two tables together.

1-to-many -- This is imply implemented by having the "id" of the "1" as a column in the "many" table.

many-to-many -- This requires an extra table with a pair of ids.  See [*Many-to-many*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) for advice on indexing.